# Stop / Play complex animation control

Tags: jquery

Have a look at: flytype.com/108

The animation that runs in the background is what I want to stop / send back to start with buttons. I have tried suggestions from "JQuery - how do I exit user defined function? thread", but the results are not quite what I was expecting. If you have the time, please take a look. Im grateful for any suggestions!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208714/stop-play-complex-animation-control/3208871#3208871) of [redsquare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6440/redsquare) is correct...

In addition you can make your codes much better by removing some `$(function(){...})`

you can just put one like this,

```
$(function(){
   // put all codes that needs to be here...
   // you can put functions, event handlers, etc...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers I have corrected the missing '$' but still the animation doesn't re-play correctly. I will attempt the second answer now...

Answer (score 1):

To start with:

Line 309 is missing a $

```
('.block','.block2','#bg1','#bg2').stop(true,true).removeAttr('style');
```